# Why this sentence uses "is" instead of "be"

Tags: sentence-construction

Bias the valve so that the anode current **is** normally zero or small

Could I write this sentence as:

Bias the valve so that the anode current be normally zero or small

Comment: "Bias the valve so that the anode current normally *becomes* (being a changed condition) zero or *a low value*." *small* probably would not be used for electricity in a technical context. Also you can leave out "normally" since the expectation is clear.

Answer (score 1):

**be** would not be grammatical, no: "so that the ... current *be*" The verb in the *that*-clause would not normally be cast in the subjunctive when giving (banal) instructions. Simple step-by-step instructions don't rise to the level of an exhortation or a mandate, where we do sometimes find the subjunctive in the *that*-clause.

In a cookbook from a few hundred years ago you might find this:

> Mix the flour with water so that it **be** well moistened.

But the subjunctive in that context would be considered an archaism in modern English.